# Why doesn't my Fade-to-Black shader go all the way to black?

Tags: three.js, webgl

here's the demo: http://percentcer.github.io/poi3d/

I have a shape being drawn on a black background that I'd like to give some sort of "light trails" effect to, which I thought I could achieve by keeping the previous framebuffer around and "darkening" it each frame (i.e. in a fragment shader, scaling each fragment vector by a value less than 1, assuming eventually the color will hit something close to vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, a) ).

Each frame, I redraw the previous frame's fragment * `some_scalar`, draw the object on top of that, and then send it through a copy shader out to screen.  I do all of this through the EffectComposer, which is used as follows.

Initialization:

```
composer  = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

shDim = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.DimShader );
composer.addPass( shDim );

var scenePass  = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
composer.addPass( scenePass );

var shCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
composer.addPass( shCopy );
```

And the animation loop:

```
shDim.uniforms[ 'prevTDiffuse' ].value = composer.writeBuffer;
composer.render();
```

( https://github.com/percentcer/poi3d/blob/master/js/logic.js#L61 )

The [DimShader](https://github.com/percentcer/poi3d/blob/master/js/shaders/DimShader.js#L31) itself isn't that complicated either:

```
fragmentShader: [

        "varying vec2 vUv;",

        "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",
        "uniform sampler2D prevTDiffuse;",
        "uniform float scaleRate;",

        "void main() {",

            "vec4 texel = texture2D( prevTDiffuse, vUv );",
            "gl_FragColor = vec4( texel.rgb * scaleRate, texel.a );",

        "}"

    ].join("\n")
```

So, repeatedly multiply a value by something less than 1 and you should get close to zero, right?  However, if you run [the demo](http://percentcer.github.io/poi3d/) you'll see that it gets *darker* but stops at some mid-tone gray value.

The default scaling rate is 0.995, which you can change with page-up and page-down.  If you go to a faster rate (0.95, page down once from the default state) the fade out will get much closer to black but still actually never reaches it, it hangs on a (very dark) gray.  Some of my friends think this is a symptom of float precision issues.  I also considered that this might be a blending issue, where the alpha value is being scaled to 0.0 so at some point the new pixel colors stop showing up, but this occurs when I force alpha to be 1.0 as well.

I'd appreciate any help, I'm new to both three.js and GLSL.  I have some openGL experience but would consider myself a beginner there as well.  Thanks!

Oh also here's the full repo:  https://github.com/percentcer/poi3d/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due the the fact that the color buffer stores discrete values. At some point

```
texel.rgb * scaleRate
```

when rounded, ends up with what you started with -- so it never goes lower.

In fact, you can predict the approximate color. For `color` in 0 to 255, solve

```
scaleRate * color = ( color - 0.5 )
```

For `scaleRate` = 0.995, `color` = 100. I observe 96 in your demo.

Comment: Thanks!  So I guess I could do the rounding operation ahead of time, in the shader, and check to see if the value WOULD change, and, if not, make the scalar larger for that frame.  Or is there a different way I should be catching these?

Comment: Try `floor( 255.0 * texel.rgb * scaleRate ) / 255.0`